# ocaml - best way to declare a function?

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to ocaml, and I'm confused on a thing:
when I declare a function, is there any difference between these way?

1)

```
let f e l = 
match l with
| []->[]
| h :: t -> if h=e then t else h :: f e t;;
```

2)

```
let e = function
h :: t -> if h=e then t else h :: f e t
| []->[];;
```

Comment: the `rec`keyword is missing in both your examples, and the name `f` is missing in the declaration 2). Appart this, both are OK, but I would tend personnaly to write 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really *in this case* (when pattern-matching on the last argument to a "multi-argument" function). The `function` keyword allows you to make a functional value with *one* argument, and when the function is applied to a value, the value is pattern-matched against the patterns.

But if I tried to pattern-match on a non-last argument, I'd use the first variant. Here is a couple examples derived from the code in the question (I swapped `e` and `l` in the function's signature):

1) It's easy, we just copy the function's body and swap the arguments at all function application places:

```
let rec f l e = match l with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> if h=e then t else h :: f t e
```

2) With `function` it's a bit cumbersome:

```
let rec f = function 
  | [] -> fun e -> []
  | h :: t -> fun e -> if h=e then t else h :: f e t
```

To understand why the second variant works, remember that multi-argument functions in OCaml are sequences of single-argument functions wrapped inside each other (it's called *currying*):

```
fun p_1 p_2 ... p_n -> body
```

is the same as

```
fun p_1 -> fun p_2 -> ... fun p_n -> body
```

**Note**: of course, if the function's body doesn't consist solely of the `match` construction, you can't use `function`.